# libreoffice not starting(with no errors!)

Tags: libreoffice

I'm trying to start libreoffice from launcher or terminal, but it just doesn't show up!
The weird thing is that it doesn't show any errors or something, and it has an exit code of 0.
And I don't know why, but it will start if with superuser permission!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does LibreOffice still show up in the processes?

This happened to me in multiple programs, and the UI just wouldn't launch.
But when I ran `ps aux`, it would show up.

In that case, I had to kill the process, and then when I tried to run it again, it would run perfectly.

Comment: This sounds like similar problem I had: soffice.bin would show up in the processer, but UI wouldn't show up until the process was killed and started again. This happened on LibreOffice 3.x (now on 4.x, I do not remember the exact version).

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: Does libreoffice --version give you any output?

Comment: Does libreoffice --safe-mode    show you anything interesting.  It can sometimes be used to correct a broken profile.

Comment: Also, please edit the question to report these last two commands and this one, too:     which libreoffice

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue but the solution was much simpler!

The LibreCal was opening but it was opening like a really small window that was not visible at all, just had to drag the corner and enlarge the screen!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can remove it completely using synaptic package manager, and try reinstall it. :) . Or if u sure ur libreoffice only run using superuser maybe it's only permisions problem. Go to ur libreoffice instalation directory ...usually in /opt/libreoffice/ or /usr. and change permision to 755. if u excecute libreoffice actually is link to soffice so change permisions soffice. like this : [image]